# Получить значения из блока span

Tags: javascript, html

Каким образом на чистом JavaScript получить текст, который обернут в блок **span**. id блоку повесить нельзя. известно только название класса.

Я пытался вот так:

```js
var price;

price = document.getElementsByClassName('name2');

alert(price.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="name2">iii</span>

<span class="name2">еще текст</span>
```

не выходит.
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращаясь к `document.getElementsByClassName('name2')`, вы обращаетесь к массиву элементов с классом `name2`. Чтобы обратиться к первому из них, надо указать его порядковый номер в массиве.

```js
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('name2');
alert(price[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="name2">iii</span>
```